# Single word for 'circulation of documents'

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a kind of technical/accounting term in Russian: *документооборот* or *делопроизводство*. It describes the set of actions and processes for the purpose of formal document management in a large organization. For example, documents should be reviewed, approved, tagged, properly structured, have mandatory references, etc. Dictionary suggests to use "documents circulation", but I'm afraid that's not what I want. I expect there to be another word (or combination) I can use. Would you suggest any?

Comment: circulationofdocuments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term that you are looking for could be one of:

- [Paperwork](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paperwork)
- [Record-keeping](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recordkeeping)
- [Procedure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/procedure) (*The set of established forms or methods of an organized body for accomplishing a certain task or tasks.*)
- Document management/Content management/Record management

Comment: I've been with a company that used the terms "document control" and "document governance", as well.

Answer (score 2):

"Processing of documents" is often used to describe the procedure you have described above.

Answer (score 2):

*[Promulgation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/promulgation)* or *to [promulgate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/promulgate#Verb)* is the official and approved distribution of a document or publication.